# How to use JavaScript modules?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to do a simple process using the skypack (https://cdn.skypack.dev/) module in javascript.

I have described the following script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button" onclick="mybutton">click</button>
    <!-- <script type="module" src="https://cdn.skypack.dev/@...<modulename>...">// <- Uncaught ReferenceError: mybutton is not defined -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.skypack.dev/@...<modulename>...">// <- Uncaught SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module
        import { METHOD } from "<modulename>";
        function mybutton(){
            console.log("aaa");
            // ... snip ...
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the module does not work in the script tag.

I have tried two things.

1. import in the script tag.

This gave me the following error.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module`.

It seems that you need to use `<script type="module"`  when importing a module.

2. do `script type="module"` .

This gave the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: mybutton is not defined`.

It seems that the function defined directly below is not found.

What can I do to resolve these?

Comment: Modules create their own namespace, variables and functions defined inside a module are not global. You've to learn how to program without global variables. To resolve the specific event listener issue at hands, see [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: There's also another error in your code. When a script tag contains an src attribute, the content of the tag is ignored.

Comment: @Teemu How can I use functions defined within a module?
How can I program without global variables?

Comment: @Teemu I see. So that's why `mybutton` is missing.
However, I think there are many times when you want to refer to a method in a module from a button click event like this.
How do you do this?

Comment: Like said in my earlier comment, use `addEventListener`. Inline listeners (or globals as well) are not recommended to be used at all (even without modules). When you write a script type of module, programming without globals comes along the module almost for free, only that you can't use inline listeners, and communicating with other browsing contexts has to be done with events.

Comment: @Teemu I used `addEventLiestener` as you described.
I am getting the expected results for the button click events.
However, I still don't know how to reference the module.


In the example above, `import { METHOD } from "<modulename>"` gives `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`.
Is there a way to reference a module?

Comment: You've to add `type="module"` to the script tag.

Comment: @Teemu You are correct.
For some reason I did not notice it when I wrote my first code.
Thanks for your patience and answering my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post the code that worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button">click</button>
    <script type="module">
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', mybutton);
        import { METHOD } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/.../<modulename>";
        function mybutton(){
            console.log("aaa");
            // METHOD(arg); ...
            // ... snip ...
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```